# StaggeredGridLayoutManager Pinch Zoom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, pinchzoom

I'd like to implement a Calendar Day View using StaggeredGridLayoutManager, and was wondering if there is a simple way to take care of pinch/zoom. I've come across usages of ScaleGestureDetector, but on other views; not on StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

Any pointers on the direction I should take would be very helpful. Thanks.